# Selenium Webdriver переключение на новое окно

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Во время работы браузера возникает новое отдельное окно браузера. Можно ли как нибудь им управлять? Окно появляется именно как копия браузера, а не как вкладка.
Появляющееся окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Переключиться на другое окно можно с помощью метода `driver.switch_to_window(<window_name>)`. `<window_name>` можно получить из атрибута `driver.window_handles`.

Важное замечание, что этот атрибут возвращает список, но порядок может быть не такой, в котором появлялись окна. Так что, до появления второго окна нужно запомнить айди основного, чтобы потом определить айди нового окна.